# How to execute skill effects with dynamic timers using Timers?

Tags: java, game-development

Currently, I am using the Timer to execute my skill effect. It will do heartbeat every 3 seconds with all skill effects.

Here is my code:

```
public class EffectServiceImpl extends AbsServiceAdaptor<EffectConfig> {
    private static EffectServiceImpl instance;
    private FastList<Monster> existsEffectMonsterList;
    private Timer timer;
    public static EffectServiceImpl getInstance() {
        if(null == instance) {
            instance = new EffectServiceImpl();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private EffectServiceImpl() {
        existsEffectMonsterList = new FastList<Monster>();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MonsterEffectCheckTask(), 10000, 3000); // Heartbeat every 3 seconds
    }
    public class MonsterEffectCheckTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(existsEffectMonsterList.size() > 0) {
                Monster monster;
                Effect effect;
                for(int i = 0; i < existsEffectMonsterList.size();) {
                    monster = existsEffectMonsterList.get(i);
                    if(monster.effectList.size() > 0) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < monster.effectList.size();) {
                            try {
                                effect = monster.effectList.get(j);
                                if(effect.heartbeat(monster)) {
                                    j++;
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(monster.effectList.size() == 0) {
                        existsEffectMonsterList.remove(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want not all skill effects to do heartbeat for 3 seconds. There will be heartbeat skills that are less than 3 seconds or greater than 3 seconds (ie dynamic period).

So I changed the period at `timer.schedule` to 1:

```
    ...
        timer.schedule(new MonsterEffectCheckTask(), 10000, 1);
    ...
```

Then add `Thread.sleep` to TimerTask:

```
...
if(monster.effectList.size() > 0) {
    for(int j = 0; j < monster.effectList.size();) {
        try {
            effect = monster.effectList.get(j);
            if(effect.heartbeat(monster)) {
                j++;
            }
            Thread.sleep(effect.execTime); // This is dynamic time, each effect has an `execTime`. Code `public int execTime;`
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
```

In case of code like above, I should: Use `schedule` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` or any other? Is there any solution to replace `Thread.sleep` in case want to "pause" timer? What should I set the `delay` and `period` (I know if I set it to 0 I will get an `IllegalArgumentException`, but if set to 1 is too short)? I want the effect to be heartbeat immediately after the "pause" time has expired. Furthermore, there can be many effects same heartbeat but the "pause" time of each effect is not the same.

I will appreciate your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic period"? Do you mean some skill effects might have an interval of 3 seconds, but then later might change to 5 seconds, for example?

Comment: @Basil Bourque Right. Period can be increased to 5 seconds or reduced to 1 second, ... (ie not fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Executors framework

`Timer` is now generally outmoded by the Executors framework. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Define your tasks as `Runnable` or a `Callable` objects.

Use a scheduled executor service backed by an appropriate number of threads. Then schedule each task to run repeatedly at intervals of your choosing.

To check on, or cancel, each task capture the `ScheduledFuture` object returned to you.

If you want to vary the amount of time interval between executions of your task, cancel a task via its `ScheduledFuture` object. Then reschedule with an executor service for a new interval of time.

Always shutdown the executor service before your app ends. Otherwise the backing thread pool may continue indefinitely like a zombie .

And wrap your task code to catch any Exception that inadvertently bubbles up. Otherwise future work will halt, silently.

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. So I am being brief. Search to learn more. And next time, search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

## Example code

I made an example app to show the basics of using the executors framework to more simply yet powerfully manage your background threading work.

We define a `Monster` interface, with two implementing classes, `Demon` & `Witch`. I create a few objects of these classes. The classes carry an `actOut` method. Our background task will be to run this method.

For each existing `Monster` instance, we define a `Runnable` which simply calls the `Monster::actOut` method on that instance. We schedule each runnable to run every several seconds via a `ScheduledExecutorService` object. That executor service returns a `ScheduledFuture` object to track each runnable we scheduled. We collect those future objects into either a list for `Demon` and a list for `Witch`.

We let this run for a minute. After that time elapses, we change the cadence of the `Witch` tasks. We cancel their current tasks, then schedule a new runnable object for much longer interval between executions. And we let this run for another minute. After that elapses, we shutdown the app.

(By the way, we could have recycled existing `Runnable` objects rather than instantiate new ones when rescheduling. Do whichever makes sense for your needs.)

This code uses some of the upcoming features previewed in Java 15 such as [sealed types](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360) and [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384).  But those are not critical to the concepts here; you could easily re-do this code using previous versions of Java.

### Sample run

Example run:

```
---------|  Starting  |--------------------------------------------
This monster Demon named Crowley buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:32:39Z
This monster Demon named Barthamus buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:32:39Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:41Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:41Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:46Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:46Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:51Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:51Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:56Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:32:56Z
This monster Demon named Crowley buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:32:59Z
This monster Demon named Barthamus buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:32:59Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:01Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:01Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:06Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:06Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:11Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:11Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:16Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:16Z
This monster Demon named Crowley buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:33:19Z
This monster Demon named Barthamus buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:33:19Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:21Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:21Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:26Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:26Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:31Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:31Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:36Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:36Z
---------|  Changing speeds  |--------------------------------------------
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:38Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:33:38Z
This monster Demon named Crowley buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:33:39Z
This monster Demon named Barthamus buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:33:39Z
This monster Demon named Crowley buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:33:59Z
This monster Demon named Barthamus buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:33:59Z
This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:34:18Z
This monster Witch named Tasha casts a spell at 2020-12-08T02:34:18Z
This monster Demon named Crowley buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:34:19Z
This monster Demon named Barthamus buys a soul at 2020-12-08T02:34:19Z
---------|  Ending  |--------------------------------------------
```

### Source code

We have four classes:

- `Monster.java` (interface for our business objects)

  - `Demon.java` (concrete class)
  - `Witch.java` (concrete class)
- `MonsterMash.java` (app class)

Code:

```java
package work.basil.example;

public sealed interface Monster
        permits Demon, Witch
{
    String name ( ); // This getter method implemented implicitly by `record` in our concrete classes `Demon` & `Witch`.

    public void actOut ( );
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public record Demon(String name) implements Monster
{
    @Override
    public void actOut ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "This monster " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " named " + this.name + " buys a soul at " + Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) );
    }
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public record Witch(String name) implements Monster
{
    @Override
    public void actOut ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "This monster " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " named " + this.name + " casts a spell at " + Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) );
    }
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Example for showing a change in cadence to scheduled tasks.
 */
public class MonsterMash
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        MonsterMash app = new MonsterMash();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        // Instantiate Monster objects.
        List < Monster > monsters = List.of(
                new Demon( "Crowley" ) ,
                new Demon( "Barthamus" ) ,
                new Witch( "Rowena" ) ,
                new Witch( "Tasha" )
        );
        System.out.println( "monsters = " + monsters );

        // Schedule each monster to do some work periodically.
        System.out.println( "---------|  Starting  |--------------------------------------------" );
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = null;
        try
        {
            ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

            final List < ScheduledFuture > demonFutures = new ArrayList <>();
            final List < ScheduledFuture > witchFutures = new ArrayList <>();
            for ( Monster monster : monsters )
            {
                Runnable runnable = monster :: actOut;  // Method reference used here for shorter syntax. 

                // Remember these futures.
                if ( monster instanceof Demon )
                {
                    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnable , 1 , 20 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
                    demonFutures.add( scheduledFuture );
                }
                if ( monster instanceof Witch )
                {
                    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnable , 3 , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
                    witchFutures.add( scheduledFuture );
                }
            }

            // Wait a while to let the scheduled tasks do their work on background thread(s).
            // Then alter the cadence of the tasks’ execution.
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 1 ) );
                System.out.println( "---------|  Changing speeds  |--------------------------------------------" );
                for ( ScheduledFuture witchFuture : witchFutures )
                {
                    witchFuture.cancel( false );
                }
                witchFutures.clear();
                for ( Monster monster : monsters )
                {
                    if ( monster instanceof Witch )
                    {
                        Runnable runnable = monster :: actOut;
                        ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( runnable , 0 , 40 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
                        witchFutures.add( scheduledFuture );
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 1 ) );

                System.out.println( "---------|  Ending  |--------------------------------------------" );
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( Objects.nonNull( ses ) ) { ses.shutdown(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see any problem with this answer. The answer clearly describes all necessary steps which any developer should be able to understand and do. If at all, one feels that the answer should be improved, leaving a comment before down-voting will help the community.

Comment: Basil Bourque - You forgot to put the link to the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. My code was written a few years ago, because of some limitations the `Timer` brings, I think it's time to upgrade it!

Comment: @ TầnQuảng I added example code that you might find helpful.

Comment: @BasilBourque In case of code like above, I should: Use `schedule` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` or any other? Is there any solution to replace `Thread.sleep` in case want to "pause" timer? What should I set the `delay` and `period` (I know if I set it to 0 I will get an `IllegalArgumentException`, but if set to 1 is too short)? I want the effect to be heartbeat immediately after the "pause" time has expired. Furthermore, there can be many effects same heartbeat but the "pause" time of each effect is not the same.

Comment: @TầnQuảng As the Javadoc says,  the `schedule` method runs your task once, after an initial delay. The `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` methods run your task repeatedly. We call `Thread.sleep` here only for demo purposes, so our the app does not exit before the background tasks are done. No `Timer` involved at all.

Comment: @TầnQuảng You can set initialDelay and period arguments to whatever amount of time makes sense for your intentions. Set initialDelay to zero if you want the first run of a task to happen immediately. Set initialDelay to some number if you want to stagger other scheduled tasks, wait for some other setup work, or want to begin at a certain time-of-day. All this has been covered in the many existing Questions and Answers on using scheduled executor service, so search to learn more.